# React how to render array elements once?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, rss, rendering

I'm trying to render items from an RSS feed after the user clicks on a button that takes them to another page, but upon loading the new page, the items are rendered multiple times. I have removed and am aware of the purpose of *React.StrictMode*. How can I fix this issue?

Here is what is rendered when looping through the first 3 items in the array:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qssic.png

Here is my code:

### Home.js

```
return(    
     <Router><Link to="/marinersfeed">
       <div class="d-grid gap-2"> <Button size='lg' id='billsViewMoreButton'> View More</Button> </div>
     </Link><Route path="/marinersfeed" component={MarinersFeed} /></Router>
)
```

### MarinersFeed.js

```
function MarinersFeed() 
  {
     ///removed this because I don't want to post my herokuapp link
      const herokuapplink = "";



      const completeFeed = [];
      const feedTitle = [];
      const feedLink = [];

      let Parser = require('rss-parser');
      let parser = new Parser();

      (async () => {

            let feed = await parser.parseURL(herokuapplink.concat('https://www.mlb.com/mariners/feeds/news/rss.xml'));

            feed.items.forEach(item => {
              

                  completeFeed.push(item.title + ':' + item.link);
                  feedTitle.push(item.title);
                  feedLink.push(item.link);
     
            });

            for (let index = 0; index < completeFeed.length; index++) {
                  
                  const title = feedTitle[index];
                  const link = feedLink[index];
                 
                  render(
                  <>
                  <h3>{index}</h3>
                  <h3>{title}</h3>
                       
                  <h3>{link}</h3>
                  <br></br>
                        </>,document.getElementById('home')
                  )
                  
                  }
                  

      })();
      
      render (
            <>
                  <div id='home'></div>
                  
            </>
      )
  }




 

 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qssic.png
```

Comment: Hi @corbinc1998. First of all you have to write code with side effect(the async code you are calling in the MarinersFeed component) inside a useEffect block. Second of all, when you do, you can define a boolean in the state of your component and set it to true after initial render and later on check that inside your useEffect block to control one time run.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use useEffect in order to render content.

Do something like this

```
function MarinersFeed () {

  
const [completeFeed, setCompletedFeed] = React.useState([]);
const [feedTitle, setFeedTitle] = React.useState([]);
const [feedLink, setFeedLink] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect(async ()=> {
let Parser = require('rss-parser');
      let parser = new Parser();

      const tFeed = [];
      const tFeedTitle = [];
      const tFeedLink = []

     let feed = await parser.parseURL(herokuapplink.concat('https://www.mlb.com/mariners/feeds/news/rss.xml'));
            feed.items.forEach(item => {
  
                  tFeed.push(item.title + ':' + item.link);
                  tFeedTitle.push(item.title);
                  tFeedLink.push(item.link);
     
            });

            setCompletedFeed(tFeed);
              setFeedTitle(tFeedTitle);
                setFeedLink(tFeedLink);
            

},[]);


const renderData = ()=> {
  return completeFeed.map((f,index)=> {

       const title = feedTitle[index];
                  const link = feedLink[index];

              return <div key={index} >

  <h3>{index}</h3>
                  <h3>{title}</h3>
                       
                  <h3>{link}</h3>

</div>
  })

          

      
      
      render (
            <>
                  <div id='home'></div>
                  {renderData()}
            </>
      )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this errors with: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'completeFeed' of undefined**

Comment: I've done some tinkering - still no luck. If you could help me out further that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @corbinc1998 what error you are facing now?

Comment: still getting the error orf: TypeError: Cannot read property 'completeFeed' of undefined